# Selecting row with minimum date while summing another column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have below Table in MySQL:

[image]

I want to fetch sum of `count` column but the expiry date should be shown either null or the smallest date with `group by package_id`.

I have below query currently:

```
select mt.id, mt.package_id, sum(mt.count), mt.expiry_date
from my_table mt left join my_table mt2 on mt.id = mt2.id and mt.expiry_date < mt2.expiry_date
group by mt.package_id;
```

It gives below result:

[image]

My required result should have `2` as id in first row instead of `1` and the `expiry_date` should be minimum which is `2010-01-01 00:00:00`:

[image]

Comment: please don't add data as images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Sure will edit my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to a query that calculates the total and returns the minimum date:

```
select m.id, m.package_id, t.total, m.expiry_date
from my_table m
inner join (
  select package_id, 
         sum(count) total, 
         min(expiry_date) expiry_date
  from my_table
  group by package_id
) t on t.package_id = m.package_id and t.expiry_date <=> m.expiry_date
```

I use the [`NULL-safe equal operator <=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) for `expiry_date` in the `ON` clause just in case the min `expiry_date` is `null`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4cf554e240f4d3592fc369ddb8f69741).
Results:

```
> id | package_id | total | expiry_date
> -: | ---------: | ----: | :----------
>  2 |          3 |    20 | 2010-01-01 
>  3 |          4 |    40 | 2011-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, but if you add 2 more rows against package_id=5 with expiry_date null in both rows, your query returns both rows. Please check this now (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c7c1cf224d76dc1e4c5c51cdc34e4011)

Comment: In this case which row do you want in the results?

Comment: Any row, can be first one of that package_id. I think adding `group by m.package_id` will do the trick? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you select min(id).

Comment: Without min(id) as well, if I just add group by it merges the rows where package_id is 5.

Comment: It just returns a row that is undetermined. If this is what you want fine. If you want the min id by code check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d4a2220f11630f60e8c407e174a5bb34

Comment: If you are able to just group by package_id this means that the flag ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. In any case it is better to group by all columns.

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you so much for your help.